# My mergesort algorythm is slower with OpenMP, how can I make it faster then the serialized form?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp, mergesort

I'm doing a study on parallel programming and testing it on Sorting algorithms. 
The easiest way I found to do it is using OpenMP, as it offer a simple way to implement threads.
I did a research and found that other people already done it, and then I tried some codes. But, when I test it with `perf stat -r 10 -d` on Linux I'm getting a worse time than the serialized code (in some cases it is double the time).
I tried with a different number of elements on the array, the maximum I used was 1.000.000 numbers, as if I use more I get a error.

```cpp
void merge(int aux[], int left, int middle, int right){
    int temp[middle-left+1], temp2[right-middle];
    for(int i=0; i<(middle-left+1); i++){
        temp[i]=aux[left+i];
    }
    for(int i=0; i<(right-middle); i++){
        temp2[i]=aux[middle+1+i];
    }
    int i=0, j=0, k=left;
    while(i<(middle-left+1) && j<(right-middle))
    {
        if(temp[i]<temp2[j]){
            aux[k++]=temp[i++];
        }
        else{
            aux[k++]=temp2[j++];
        }
    }
    while(i<(middle-left+1)){
        aux[k++]=temp[i++];
    }
    while(j<(right-middle)){
        aux[k++]=temp2[j++];
    }
}

void mergeSort (int aux[], int left, int right){
    if (left < right){
        int middle = (left + right)/2;
        omp_set_num_threads(2);
        #pragma omp parallel
        {

            #pragma omp sections
            {
                #pragma omp section
                    mergeSort(aux,left,middle); //call 1
                #pragma omp section
                    mergeSort(aux,middle+1,right); //call 2
            }
        }
        merge(aux,left,middle,right);
    }
}

int main(){
    generate_list(Vet, n);
    mergeSort(Vet, 0, n-1);

    return(0);
}
```

Below are the results i'm receiving:

OpenMP code:

Performance counter stats for `./mergeomp` (10 runs):

```
         12,489169      task-clock (msec)         #    0,717 CPUs utilized            ( +-  3,58% )
                 8      context-switches          #    0,681 K/sec                    ( +-  6,62% )
                 0      cpu-migrations            #    0,000 K/sec                  
               167      page-faults               #    0,013 M/sec                    ( +-  0,79% )
   <not supported>      cycles                                                      
   <not supported>      instructions                                                
   <not supported>      branches                                                    
   <not supported>      branch-misses                                               
   <not supported>      L1-dcache-loads                                             
   <not supported>      L1-dcache-load-misses                                       
   <not supported>      LLC-loads                                                   
   <not supported>      LLC-load-misses                                             

           0,01743 +- 0,00211 seconds time elapsed  ( +- 12,10% )
```

Serialized way(simple code):

Performance counter stats for `./mergesort` (10 runs):

```
          3,757053      task-clock (msec)         #    0,449 CPUs utilized            ( +-  0,72% )
                 1      context-switches          #    0,293 K/sec                    ( +- 16,32% )
                 0      cpu-migrations            #    0,000 K/sec                  
               139      page-faults               #    0,037 M/sec                    ( +-  0,34% )
   <not supported>      cycles                                                      
   <not supported>      instructions                                                
   <not supported>      branches                                                    
   <not supported>      branch-misses                                               
   <not supported>      L1-dcache-loads                                             
   <not supported>      L1-dcache-load-misses                                       
   <not supported>      LLC-loads                                                   
   <not supported>      LLC-load-misses                                             

          0,008375 +- 0,000276 seconds time elapsed  ( +-  3,29% )
```

Am I doing anything wrong? I'm compiling it with the `-fopenmp` flag, but don't know if merge sort is not good to be parallelized, or if my linux virtual machine (I'm running Ubuntu on a VM Virtual Box machine, my PC have a Core I7 processor) is not well configured.

Comment: Just for completeness: Did you check that your algorithm is correct? Does `std::is_sorted(Vet, Vet+n)` return `true`?

Comment: If the processor has 4 cores, you could split the array into 4 parts, then sort the 4 parts using 4 threads. Then 2 threads could be each be used to merge a pair of sorted quarters, and 1 thread used to merge the two sorted halves. I did this in C++ and it was about 3 times as fast as a single threaded merge sort.

Comment: You are calling `omp_set_num_threads(2)` as often as `n/2` times. I don't know how your implementation handles that, but there's no point in doing it more than once in my understanding.

Comment: How many CPUs have you configured for your VM?

Comment: Also, unless you enable nested parallelism, you won't have more than two threads running...

Comment: And finally, did you compile with optimizations enabled?

Comment: One possible configuration problem would be the use of hyper-threading. If it is one, and both threads are placed on the same physical core,  there will be a lot of cash misses. If it is on, disable it and try it again

Comment: 1) You should use a problem size that takes a significant amount of time. 2) Please provide a [mcve]. 3) Provide information on how you compile the code 4) Provide more system information  - how many cores did you assign to the VM? what is the specific processor specification?

Comment: @MaxLanghof, is_sorted is returning true. So firt of all it's working.
This is how I compile it:
 g++ mergeomp.cpp -o mergeomp -fopenmp

Comment: @molbdnilo it seems I missed this part, now i'm running the machine with 4 CPUs, but still geting slower time in parallel

Comment: If anyone want to check my code https://pastebin.com/qAKtkMZh

Comment: You should enable optimizations (`-O3`). Reasoning about the speed of unoptimized code is pretty pointless. And if your code takes < 1 millisecond to run (which it likely will once you enable optimizations) then your profiling results will probably be mostly noise (like the program and threads starting up).

Comment: Zulan, check on comments ahead, I think I answered most of you asked me, I running a virtual machine on a I7 computer, using 4 CPUS for it, 4GB of ram memory, using Linux Ubuntu 18.system. Here is a screenshot of the virtual machine:https://ibb.co/C9s945R

Comment: https://pastebin.com/rY2ya6Hm @MaxLanghof, I used the -O3 and the result get better (about 2 ms better)

Comment: @Luiz You're most likely measuring how long it takes for the program and multiple threads to be started, not how long the actual sorting takes once that is done. Just repeat the stuff in your main loop many times (without restarting the program).

Comment: You should not be using the `sections`construct.  It has been superseded by the `task` construct, which allows task-based parallelism at runtime, not at compile-time. With that, you will also be able to support more than just a single split and you can enable full recursion and gain more parallelism out of the code.

Comment: @MichaelKlemm I Used tasks now, here's my new implementation: https://pastebin.com/QrDa3B5d .

Comment: Here are the results: https://pastebin.com/zwXmnYfa

Comment: You don't get any parallelism with this version of the code, as you do not spawn any threads to execute the tasks in parallel.  You'll have to rename `mergeSort` to `mergeSortTasked` and introduce a new function like this:


`void mergeSort(int aux[], int left, int right) {
    #pragma omp parallel
    #pragma omp master
        mergeSortTasked(aux, left, right);
}`

Comment: ok, corrected this using ```int main(){
 generate_list(Vet, n);
    #pragma omp parallel
   {
      #pragma omp single
   mergeSort(Vet, 0, n-1);
   }```

Comment: Last result: https://pastebin.com/r71wXVbR still not good though ...

Comment: https://pastebin.com/xbK5hbGt the last version of my code, runned 10 times the threaded part.

Comment: I think there are two reasons why you do not see any speed-up: 1) your data size of 100k is too small for the parallelization to pay off; 2) your task granularity is too small.  Re 1), please try larger arrays, say 1000k or more. Re 2), please introduce a cutoff that stops the task creating in the recursion when the array partition is about 1k elements and switch to a sequential mergeSort then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193163/discussion-between-luiz-and-michael-klemm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for everyone I resolved the issue.

First of all I had not setted multicores on my Virtual Machine.

Then, I changed the `sections` construct for `task`.

I also used a bigger number of elements on my array (2 Million).

And finally I added a filter to stop using parallelism when the array is smaller then "n" elements:

```cpp
void mergeSortSerial(int aux[], int left, int right){
    if (left < right){
        int middle = (left + right)/2;
        mergeSortSerial(aux,left,middle); //call 1
        mergeSortSerial(aux,middle+1,right); //call 2
        merge(aux,left,middle,right);
    }
}

void mergeSort (int aux[], int left, int right){
    if (left < right){
        if ((right-left) > 1000){
            int middle = (left + right)/2;
           #pragma omp task firstprivate (aux, left, middle)
                mergeSort(aux,left,middle); //call 1
            #pragma omp task firstprivate (aux, middle, right)
                mergeSort(aux,middle+1,right); //call 2
            #pragma omp taskwait
            merge(aux,left,middle,right);
        } else{mergeSortSerial(aux, left, right);}
    }
}
```

I found out that 1.000.000 is the best number for "n", my algorithm is 2 times faster then the sequential.